# Android getter and setter, database sqlite(helper class)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table on a database with two columns, and then i am trying to use webservice,JSON parse some data from some URL to the database and save it. I try to do that in this method

```
  public void saveDataRecord(String id, String name) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
```

However i am also having model class(which contain setter and getter), that can be use when i try to read data from database using list(it works on my previous object that have database inside and the values already inserted). Now i want to use that because it has the parameters and can be useful to read list(take a look at the bottom code). I am a bit confuse, what to use getId,getName or setId,setName?
this?

```
public void saveDataRecord(TheModelClass blablabla) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, blablabla.getId());
            contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, blablalbla.getName());
            database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

or this?

```
 public void saveDataRecord(TheModelClass blablabla) {
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, blablabla.setId());
                contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, blablalbla.setName());
                database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
```

even tho i did this on my other project

```
public List<TheModelClass> getAllEffectiveRates() {
        List<TheModelClass> EffectiveRates = new ArrayList<TheModelClass>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                TheModelClass example = new TheModelClass();
                example.setERId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_ID)));
                example.setERTenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_TENOR)));
                example.setERRate(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_RATE)));

                // add
                EffectiveRates.add(example);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        // db.close();
        c.close();
        return EffectiveRates;
    }
```

I am still confuse with what getter and setter do exactly

Comment: should i use get or set????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getter basically returns the data held by that instance. Setter sets the data to be held by the instance.

In your case, while inserting data, you should use the getters as the values in the ContentValues instance. So it should be:

```
public void saveDataRecord(TheModelClass blablabla) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, blablabla.getId());
    contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, blablalbla.getName());
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

Getters will return a value. Setters (in general) will not return a value. So if you use the setter, you will only be setting the value of the instance in ContentValues but you will not actually be using it as the call will not return anything.

Comment: its like get from input ,then put into, and last insert into the table. Am i right?

Answer (score 4):

yes you can use Get Set method

```
public class GetSetClass {

// private variables
int _id;
String _data;


// Empty constructor
public GetSetClass() {
}

// constructor
public GetSetClass(int id, String data) {
    this._id = id;
    this._DataList_id = DataList_id;
}

// constructor
public GetSetClass(String data) {
    this._data = data;
}

// getting ID
public int getID() {
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public String getdata() {
    return this._data;
}

public void setdata(String data) {
    this._data = data;
}
}
```

**see below code for set data using getset**

```
public List<GetSetClass> getAllgetsets() {
    List<GetSetClass> getsetList = new ArrayList<GetSetClass>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            GetSetClass getset = new GetSetClass();
            getset.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            getset.setData(cursor.getString(1));
            getsetList.add(getset);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return getset list
    return getsetList;
}
```

**see below code for Get data using getset**

```
public int updategetset(GetSetClass getset) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_data, getset.getData()); 

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CATEGORY, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(getset.getID()) });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to understand more about working with objects, and use of parcelables.
Here is a very usefull tools that generate all code you need including Table, Model, classes for Insert and more:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842150/Generator-for-SQLite-Use-in-Android
```

Create a table call Dic with Id, Name, Code
In android for put EditText for name and code and onse save button, then onclick

```
dic.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
dic.setCode(edtCode.getText().toString());
database.Open()
database.insert(dic);
database.close();
```

If you want to show data from datebase to form:

```
Dic dic = new DIc();
database.open();
dic = database.findDic("id = 1");
database.Close;
lblName.setText(dic.getName().toString());
lblCode.setText(dic.getCode().toString());
```

Add one package for Models, and put each model in a seperate file here.
Add one package for Db
Add two file one as OpenHelper.Java, and one for Database.java for easy mangement of code

Answer (score 0):

```
 DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(this);

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name, phone;
            txtName = findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtPhone = findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

            name = txtName.getText().toString();
            phone = txtPhone.getText().toString();
            if (!(name.equals("") && phone.equals(""))) {
                Entity entity = new Entity();
                entity.setName(name);
                entity.setPhone(phone);

                helper.insertData(entity);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fill the Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Entity {

    private int id;
    private String name, phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insertData(Entity entity) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, entity.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, entity.getPhone());

        database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your code how it works and how it answers the OP's question.